# Encrypt client-side / Decrypt server-side JS - PHP

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, cryptography

I tried doing client side encryption using js and server-side decryption using php, been debugging for hours only to find out that even though they have the same encryption method, they don't match, regardless of size, etc.

There are many cryptographic js libraries available and the crypt(), mcrypt, functions in php are deprecated.

I tried searching for a pair (ex. AES.js and AES.php) but none of them worked out

Can you suggest what good encryption method to use? How to implement them. 'Cause I believe there is a key or something, and I also heard about IVs, I don't even know about that.

jQuery (using simple sha256)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#login").on("submit", function(event) {
        var pass = $("#pass").val();
        $("#pass").val(CryptoJS.SHA256(pass));
        var data = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt($(this).serialize(), $("#token").val());
        $("#login").submit();
    });
});
```

I want to try decrypting it in php but mcrypt_decrypt is deprecated. There is this openssl that I don't know how to use.

Comment: You should show some efforts here. Let us know how you are doing so and what problem you have faced

Comment: I've been using CryptoJS.AES.encrypt() function in js but I don't know how to match it with php. I did search in the php manual and all I saw was a deprecated crypt() and mcrypt_decrypt(). and the openssl is also not properly documented. In general, I've been doing trial and error since I slightly don't have a clue in the process of encrypting/decrypting.  I know how to hash though.

Comment: There are multiple flavors of different encryption algo. Also you must have used some keys to encrypt the data. That's imp when you try to decryptioning your cipher back. So share your code for encryption and decryption here

Comment: You have stored your hash value in elemnt with id pass, and try to encrypt value from element with id token? Are you sure you are doing right? Ok tell me, what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: hashing my password and then encrypt the entire form querystring. since the password is already hashed when stored. I just did it for extra security. Is it bad?

Comment: I did used my token as a key to compare it in the php session. I don't know how to make shared keys between javascript and php @@

Comment: You can do so, its all depends on your use case. Ok looks OK. Now how you are trying to decrypt it?

Comment: I googled how to decrypt this in php but they all doing it the "hard" way. I mean, I did found some built-in functions in php like decrypt() and mcrypt_decrypt() but they discouraged to use them since it's deprecated and most of the tutorials are pretty old.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may try this code to decrypt in PHP

```
$Pass = "Passwort";
$Clear = "Klartext";        

$crypted = fnEncrypt($Clear, $Pass);
echo "Encrypred: ".$crypted."</br>";

$newClear = fnDecrypt($crypted, $Pass);
echo "Decrypred: ".$newClear."</br>";        

function fnEncrypt($sValue, $sSecretKey)
{
    return rtrim(
        base64_encode(
            mcrypt_encrypt(
                MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
                $sSecretKey, $sValue, 
                MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, 
                mcrypt_create_iv(
                    mcrypt_get_iv_size(
                        MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, 
                        MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
                    ), 
                    MCRYPT_RAND)
                )
            ), "\0"
        );
}

function fnDecrypt($sValue, $sSecretKey)
{
    return rtrim(
        mcrypt_decrypt(
            MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, 
            $sSecretKey, 
            base64_decode($sValue), 
            MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,
            mcrypt_create_iv(
                mcrypt_get_iv_size(
                    MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
                    MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
                ), 
                MCRYPT_RAND
            )
        ), "\0"
    );
}
```

I didn't checked it, butyou may try.

Comment: is it still okay to use mcrypt? I saw this earlier

Comment: @EhmzYoshinoMamei This PHP code isn't remotely doing the same thing as the JavaScript code in the question. Why did you accept it? Have you tested it?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I am supposed to try it but I was instructed to do other modules first. I still have no idea about decrypting in php